# How to call a multer upload function outside of handler

Tags: javascript, express, file-upload, multer

I would like to dynamically set the storage destination for uploading a file using multer in my express app, as well as the name of the file.
I have an express route that handles a post request as shown:

EJS:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="somename">
    <select name="p">
        <option selected>ABC</option>
        <option>DEF</option> 
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="dtYear" value="2020">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

ExpressJS:

```
let storageDest = './public/content/dts/' ;
let fileName;
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, storageDest)
        console.log(file);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (fs.existsSync(storageDest + file.originalname)){
            fileName = file.fieldname + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
        } else{
            fileName = file.originalname;
        }

        cb(null, fileName)
    }
})

const upload = multer({storage: storage})

app.post('/upload', upload.single('somename'), (req, res, next) => {
    storageDestiantion += req.body.p.toLowerCase() + '/';
    fileName = req.body.dtYear;
    res.send('Thank you for uploading!')
})
```

However, I can only change the `storageDestination` and `fileName` variables before the multer `upload.single()` function is called for them to have any effect, as if I change them after the function call, the file is already uploaded.

Is there a way to call the `upload.single()` function after making the above changes, or does it have to be a parameter of the `app.post()` function - if it does, is there a workaround to achieve what I desire?

Comment: how does the program know when to change and to what? Where's that code? Then, notice that the `(req, res, next) =>`  method is a parameter to `app.post`.   Make this parameter a variable instead of hard coding it.

Comment: @radarbob Sorry, the code has been added. I am quite new to express, what do you mean by making the `(req, res, next) =>` a variable instead of hard coding it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Look at your `app.post` method and match up the parents and you'll see `post` has 3 parameters. Replace the 3rd parameter - which starts with `(req, res, next) ...` with a variable. Somewhere before `post` is called, set the variable to the desired function.